# Which process places a red circle to the bottom right corner of my display on Linux Mint 18.1?

Tags: linux-mint, gui, malware

Some days ago that widget appeared on screen and I have no idea how to remove it and how did it came to my system. Not taken by screenshots. I suggest it is malware. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Appears you have an external monitor attached. If so, try attaching a different monitor + see if dot relates to code running or monitor attached.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Look here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/more-gnome-shell-tips-and-tricks/
Scroll down to 6 "Screencast Recording".

It says:

> Unknown to many, Gnome Shell has a built-in screen recorder. At any point of time, you just have to press the shortcut key “Shift + Ctrl + Alt + R” to activate the screen recorder. Once activated, you will see a recording button at the bottom right corner. Press “Shift + Ctrl + Alt + R” again to stop the recording. It will then save itself with the filename “shell-date-string-counter.webm” in your Home folder.

Comment: Thanks this is just what I was looking for after a panicked search for malware on my system that turned up nothing!

Comment: LOL just ran into this now ... must be way too tired, but thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Nice.  Just found out I was recording the screen for 18 hours -- made a 4G file in 1920x1080.